# Row w/ null column returned first when querying for (column = ? OR column is null)

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a table for storing notification settings.  In this table, notification settings have a `type`, `user_id` and `options` column. Any rows with a NULL `user_id` FK represent default setting values, and any changes made by a user to their settings is upserted onto the table with their `user_id`.

My `User#fetchSettings` function accepts an array of types to fetch, or fetches all of them if no types are provided. The function should return a setting for each type requested, returning rows with their `user_id` over rows where `user_id` is NULL. However, I can't find a way to have rows with `user_id` set take precedence over rows with NULL.

My query is as follows:

```
select distinct ON (type) 
    "type", 
    "options",
    "user_id"
from "user_settings"
where 
    (
        "user_settings"."user_id" = '1' 
        or "user_id" is null
    ) 
and "type" in ('type1', 'type2', 'type3');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You select rows by `DISTINCT ON ("type")`. This will select the first row of a set when there are multiple rows with the same type. You can favour rows with a specific `user_id` over rows with a `null` value by ordering the rows properly:

```
select distinct ON (type) 
    "type", 
    "options",
    "user_id"
from "user_settings"
where 
    (
        "user_settings"."user_id" = '1' 
        or "user_id" is null
    ) 
and "type" in ('type1', 'type2', 'type3')
order by 1, 2, 3 nulls last;
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out shortly after posting the question.  By adding an `order by` clause, I was able to place nulls after rows with user_ids set.  My new query is:

```
select distinct ON (type) 
    "type", 
    "description", 
    "options", 
    "user_id" 
from "user_settings"
where 
    (
        "user_settings"."user_id" = '385' 
        or "user_id" is null
    ) 
    and "type" in (...) 
order by "type" asc, "user_id" asc;
```

Comment: Ha! Just what I writing up for you. Use `nulls last` to be on the safe side.

Comment: Thank you I definitely will!  Sorry about that, I was hoping nobody was in the process of responding when I realized what it was!  Did not know about nulls last here though so thank you again!

Comment: No problem, it happens more often that answers are drawn up at the same time.